# st_distance() hangs with large number of points in R

Tags: r, sf, distance-matrix, euclidean

I am using `sf::st_distance()` to calculate a distance matrix in R. I have around 30,000 polygons, and I am running this analysis on a computing cluster with ~500G of RAM. I understand that 30,000 comparisons should create a matrix with 900,000,000 elements. My ultimate goal is to find all polygons that are within a specific `distance` of each other, reducing 900,000,000 elements to a more manageable size. My code (not reproducible) looks like this:

```
distmat = drop_units(st_distance(fin_poly))
distmat = distmat - distance
distmat[lower.tri(distmat)] <- NA 
diag(distmat) <- NA
comps = which(distmat < 0, arr.ind = T)
```

For smaller data sets, this code has no problem and produces the desired output. But for this large dataset, the software hangs and is only using ~30G of available memory.

Should a machine with 500G of RAM be able to handle this? And if not, is there a more efficient way to complete such a calculation?

EDIT: I have also tried the following code that uses `st_is_within_distance()`:

```
comps1=st_is_within_distance(fin_poly,dist=distance)
comps = utils::stack(setNames(comps1,1:2))[2:1]
names(comps)=c('row','col')
```

which still hangs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the number of computations, it is likely that the process would have taken a very long time (I stopped it after 8 hours of unchanging memory usage). However, by parallelizing the code, it changed the run time to only 1.5 hours. I had access to 50 cores to split the 500Gb of RAM, so instead of comparing the entire `fin_poly` shapefile to itself, I compared individual shapes within `fin_poly` to the entire shapefile. Code below:

```
library(parallel)

myCluster <- parallel::makeCluster(50)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(myCluster)

comps <- foreach::foreach(i = 1:nrow(fin_poly), .errorhandling = "remove", .combine = "rbind", .packages = c("sf", "terra")) %dopar% {
  comps1=t(st_is_within_distance(fin_poly[i,],fin_poly,dist=distance,sparse = F))
  comps1=which(comps1)
  dist_df = data.frame(row=rep(i,length(comps1)),
                       col=comps1)
  return(dist_df)
}

parallel::stopCluster(myCluster)

comps = comps %>%
  filter(row!=col)
```

Answer (score 2):

Things I'd do:

1. Time how long it takes to complete as you scale up the number of polygons, then extrapolate to estimate how long 30,000 would take. You say it "hangs" but unless you have a completion estimate its hard to tell if it is really stuck in an infinite loop or just taking a long time. Its possible there's two polygons that have some pathological relationship that triggers a bug in the distance calc and makes the calculation loop forever, but an investigation of time with problem size should tell you if the time you are letting it run is sufficient.
2. If you can, use a planar distance and not a spherical distance - reproject to cartesian coords and switch s2 off. This should make all distance calculations faster, but is not appropriate if your polygons are all over the globe and you want accurate distances on the sphere.
3. Chunk the calculations. If you can do 5,000 polygons then 36 lots of 5,000x5,000 will span the whole 30,000x30,000. If you have a cluster then you can launch all 36 jobs and if there's free nodes they should run together. Write each 5k x 5k matrix to disk and merge it in another process.

A 30,000x30,000 array is "only" about 7Gb of 8-byte numbers, so 500Gb on a node should be enough, and using 30Gb of RAM seems about right - this will all depend on the complexity of your polygons - if each one has three or four nodes then the polygons won't take much RAM, but if they are all detailed coastlines then they'll take more. Another option may be to simplify (`st_simplify`) the polygons to reduce the node count with a slight change of accuracy of inter-polygon distance.

Comment: This is very good advice, thank you. I think you are correct, the code would have just taken a very long time to run. What I ended up trying (just before you posted this answer) was parallelizing the code over 50 cores. See my self-answer below. Thank you again!